# Can I export a trained machine learning model so that others case use it?

Tags: machine-learning, training

From what I know, AI/ML uses a large amount of data to train an algorithm to solve problems. But since it’s an algorithm, I was wondering if it's possible to export it. If I trained an AI with R, could I export a mathematical algorithm that could be imported by other users to use in their application, whether it’s written in R or another language?

So it’s like I’ve discovered a secret message decoding method. I don’t need to share the whole program for others to decode it. I just need to tell them the steps (algorithm) to decode it, and they can implement it in whatever application they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'algorithm' you're talking about is a neural network, then you can distribute the learned parameters/weights to anyone who wants to use it. This is how neural nets are normally 'exported': without all of the training data used to create them. Actually, this is done with many kinds of models ([parameterized ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_family)).

In order to 'decode' the model, users would only have to know its structure. In the case of a neural network, they'd need to know the size of each layer, what activation functions were used, etc.

This is not possible with every type of ML model, however. Specifically, [non-parametric models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) and 'lazy' models make use of training data at inference time. They wouldn't be useful without their training data. Classifying an input by finding its [k nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm), for example, would require having the training data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you've trained a model you'll have the details of that model in your workspace.

e.g.

```
B_Naive = naiveBayes(train_set[,-c(1)],train_set[,1]);
```

Will give you an object B_naive that can be 'exported'. These are the parameters of the model, you'll still need the naïve bayes library (or whichever library).